# I have a problem at child class about super()

Tags: java, inheritance

This is my child class:

```
public class User extends Alien
{

protected XYCoordination currentLocation;
protected int energyCanister;
protected int lifePoints;

public User (XYCoordination currentLocation, int energyCanister, int lifePoints)
{
    super(currentLocation);
}
public int collectCanister()
{
    super.collectCanister();
    return energyCanister;
}
public int caculateLifePoints(int lifePoints)
{
    super.caculateLifePoints(lifePoints);
    return lifePoints;
}
}
```

This is my parent class:

```
public class Alien
{
protected XYCoordination currentLocation;
protected Planet currentPlanet;
protected int energyCanister;
protected int lifePoints;
protected int n;

public Alien(XYCoordination currentLocation, int energyCanister, int lifePoints)
{
    this.currentLocation = currentLocation;
    this.energyCanister = energyCanister;
    this.lifePoints = lifePoints;
}

public XYCoordination moveRight(XYCoordination toRight)
{
    currentLocation = currentLocation.addXToRight(toRight);
    return currentLocation;
}
public XYCoordination moveUp(XYCoordination toUp)
{
    currentLocation = currentLocation.addYToUp(toUp);
    return currentLocation;
}
public XYCoordination moveLeft(XYCoordination toLeft)
{
    currentLocation = currentLocation.addXToLeft(toLeft);
    return currentLocation;
}
public XYCoordination moveDown(XYCoordination toDown)
{
    currentLocation = currentLocation.addYToDown(toDown);
    return currentLocation;
}
public int collectCanister()
{
    energyCanister = energyCanister + (int)(n*currentPlanet.getRemainingCanister());
    return energyCanister;
}
public int caculateLifePoints(int lifePoints)
{
    lifePoints = (int)((2/3)*lifePoints);
    return lifePoints;
}
public void displayInfo()
{
    System.out.print("Currently you are in:" + currentLocation + "\t Currently you have" + energyCanister + "canisters" + "\tCurrently you have" + lifePoints + "lifepoints");
}
}
```

It is always says "can't find the symble 'super'."

Comment: I see nothing in your code that would cause *that* compilation error.  Copy and paste the exact compilation error, and indicate which line of your code it is occurring on.

Answer (score 4):

Your superclass needs to have a constructor that matches the signature you're calling. Since you have

```
public User (XYCoordination currentLocation, ....) {
    super(currentLocation);
}
```

the Alien class you're extending needs to have a constructor with a matching signature-

```
public Alien(YCoordination currentLocation)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? I am new.

Comment: @Charles Cai - I told you the same thing in an earlier question you asked.

Comment: @CharlesCai : Before posting such questions,I think you must read some of the basics of Java as per given in the JLS.

Answer (score 0):

When you say
super(currentLocation); 
You call the super class (parent class) constructor with the single argument `currentLocation`. But your super class Alien does not have a constructor that accepts a single argument `currentLocation`.

`Cannot find symbol super` in this context means: You are trying to call a super class constructor with a single parameter, but I am unable to find a constructor in the super class with a single `currentLocation` argument.

You probably wanted to call `super(currentLocation, energyCanister, lifePoints)`